# Spaces being inserted into paragraph text when using Wygwam

Tags: wygwam, plugin

I'm using Wygwam and it is inserting extra space into paragraphs which is making text display with an extra line top and bottom. If I click to Source view in the ee control panel, I can manually remove this and submit, then the text displays correctly. Any help would be appreciated. I'm on EE v2.6.1 and Wygwam 2.7.1. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for getting back to me. I'm sorry to have wasted your time. It was due to a rogue css style. Which has resolved the issue.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you replicate the behavior on http://ckeditor.com/demo?  If so, then it's CKEditor behavior and there isn't much we can do to affect it.